# Is there a way to show an error message while the user has not entered a valid value, within the condition of a while loop

Tags: java

I pretty new to java programming so i was wondering if there is a way to use the condition of a while loop to stop an invalid value being used.

I am writing a program that prompts the user to enter an identification number as an integer then uses a scanner to store that value.

Just wanted to know if this is possible to put something in the condition of the for loop that prints an error message if the enter something like a string, double or char so i dont get the Input Mismatch Exception.

like this:

```
    identification = userId(in); //scanner


    while (identification (is not an integer)){
        System.out.println("Invalid Value, Please enter an integer");
        identification = userId(in);
```

Comment: Scanner has a method called `hasNextInt`. You could use that

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you can write:

```
while ((identification = userId(in)) < 0) {
    System.out.println("blah ...");
}
```

The assumption is that the `userIn` method returns some negative value if the input is not an integer. You can make the invalid return value whatever you want as long as it is not something that is a valid input.

Some people don't like this style because it has gone out of fashion and they are not used to it; however, it used to be common in C programming and there is nothing about it that is implicitly unclear or bad.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are asking.  It is basically a `while` loop that waits until the next input is an integer before continuing the code.  The important part is making sure to use `in.next()` inside the `while` loop instead of `in.nextInt()` because the values could be anything.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    while (!(in.hasNextInt()))
    {
        System.out.print("Integer not entered, please enter an integer: ");
        in.next();
    }
    int value = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The int was " + value);

    in.close();
```